# I've got Supplies. Now what?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Having just arrived at Hoth, with my Imperial Agent, I checked in with the ranking officer of the Salvage operations on site at the base. He informed me that his superior is out in the field and can't be reached on standard communications channels, but that if I'd like to be a suicidal maniac and brave Republic Commandos and the frigid winds of Hoth, well, I'm more than welcome to.

*Naturally*, I pulled rank and demanded that he provide me with all the supplies and provisions that he could afford to for my mission, it being of utmost importance.

[I got these.](http://www.torhead.com/item/biYeWf0/supplies)

The item is in my bags as a standard item, not a Mission Item. The tooltip claims they are an 'optional Quest Reward'. I cannot click or use them in any way. TORhead, et al come up with nothing, but the databases are woefully imperfect at the moment. They sell to a vendor for 0 credits.

**What are these Supplies for? How do I use them? Barring that, how can I get rid of them productively?**

Comment: I would guess that, *naturally*, the man just obeyed orders and gave you what you asked for ... even though you have no possible use for it.  Kind of amusing.

Answer (score 4):

The item is said to be linked to "Frigid Expedition" as a reward, not a quest item. It might be a prank, since it might not be the correct supplies.

There are no indications that these Supplies can be used for anything, either quest related or financial gain.