# I've agreed to be the spokesperson for a new line of performance enhancing drugs. How do I use them?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So, my Bounty Hunter, having achieved a fair amount of Galactic Notoriety after winning the Great Hunt, has received an offer from Adascorp to endorse their new line of experimental Stims. Since the offer had more 0's than Mako could count, I'm going to assume that this is some Pretty Good Stuff, and I'd be crazy not to want to use it myself - after all, I'm selling it, right?

So, after meeting with an Adascorp honcho on Quesh and after an... let's call it an *incident* involving some overly demanding Jedi, I retrieved my compensation for taking on this job and was left with... [this. A Prototype Combat Stimulant.](http://www.torhead.com/item/lOP0jK/prototype-combat-stimulant)

I can't use the item, and it only vendors for 500 credits, which, even using TOR's somewhat liberal and heavily level adjusted definition of 'top credits', is a pretty paltry sum at level 36. Is there any use for this item? [Is this just another itemization dead end like the Supplies?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46124/ive-got-supplies-now-what)

Comment: `competitors will pay top credits for the chance to analyze it` makes it sound like later you'll be able to backstab them.  One can hope.

Comment: There's nothing back about the stabbing I'd be doing. I've glossed over some spoilers, but I fully intend to stab them from the front.

Answer (score 4):

[Several](http://www.swtor.com/de/community/showthread.php?t=79758) [discussions](http://www.torhead.com/item/lOP0jK/prototype-combat-stimulant) [say](http://db.darthhater.com/items/12118/prototype_combat_stimulant/#comments) that this item truly does nothing, even from a level 50 stand point. It cannot be disassembled, but can be sold to the vendor indicating it is not a quest item.

Since this is **most likely** the result of an unimplemented quest, abandoned beta quest or simply the first of a line of green trash ("flavor") items, I wouldn't lose sleep over selling it. Other MMO's don't have a history of implementing quests in patches that some players cannot complete because they had previously sold or lost an item. It just creates unnecessary support tickets.

From my personal experience, I just sold this item after reading Torhead.